# Eclipse and subclipse, adding subversion revision in comments or code

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Is there a way to add a hook to add the subversion revision to code.  For example, if I do a save, could I invoke subclipse to get the latest revision of that file and add the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're interested in Subversion's [keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) capability. Take a look at that link, but I believe $Revision$ will suit your purpose.